# what is the proper way of writing 1 square millimeter?

Tags: area

(.001m)^2 or (.001m^2)
I think it is the first one but Im not sure. Please look over these equations for me so I can have a sufficiently long question to submit.

Comment: $1mm^2=(.001m)^2=10^{-6}m^2$  You are right.

Answer (score 2):

"1 square millimeter" is usually written $1\ \mathrm{mm}^2.$
This is the area of a square whose side is $1\ \mathrm{mm}.$

If you want to convert to square meters,
$1\ \mathrm{mm}^2 = 10^{-6} \ \mathrm{m}^2.$

Answer (score 1):

I believe the second one is the correct one.

The first one makes it look like you are squaring $.001$ as well

Comment: However, the second says $.001$ of a square metre which is a lot bigger than a square of one millimetre.  I would read "1 square millimetre" as the area of a square with a side of 1 millimetre; if so then the first is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$1 mm = 0.001 m$

You can square both sides:
$1 mm^2 = 0.000001 m^2$